# Hide .woocommerce-price-suffix on the product list page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to display .woocommerce-price-suffix only on the product detail page?

.woocommerce-price-suffix .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount 
{   display:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything with a class of "woocommerce-price-suffix" on my site. But, `body.single-product .woocommerce-price-suffix { display:none; }` should do the trick.